# Access right-click menu in optimization process

Tags: batch-file, automation, right-click

I'm using an .exe program in Windows 10 (Poisson Superfish), which requires the user to right-click a file (and choose "Run Poisson") to run the solver, and then right click again (and choose "Postprocess") to output results. To optimize a design, I'd like to automate this to explore multiple configurations. I have code that will set everything up beforehand, and pull and analyze data from the post-processor results afterward, but I don't know how to access the right-click menu of the file without physically doing so.

Is there a command that I can put into a batch file to access the "Run..." and "Postprocess" commands? All searches I've done on "batch files" + "right-click" only lead to adding batch processes to right-click menus, but I want to do the reverse, i.e., to run a right-click command by executing a batch file. It's not crucial that a batch file be used, it's just that I have (basic) familiarity with them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know how to add a command, then it should be easy to find the commands currently set. But first you need to know if the `Run Poisson` exists for every file or only for specific extensions. For extensions look at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.yourextension\shell\the menu entry text\command` with the `regedit` tool

Comment: @jeb, The command only exists for these types of files, specifically .T35 files. This extension does not appear in the list under SystemFileAssociations in the registry editor.

Comment: @jeb, you sent me down the right path! I figured out a way to do it, not in the way I originally asked, but you made me realize that these right-click menu items were actually commands themselves which could be invoked directly once I found their executables in the main program directory. Thanks for the push.